# Close Fancybox modal window and reload the page after login form has been submitted

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've got a login form opening in a FancyBox 2 modal iframe window. But when you submit the form, the web page is opening within the modal.

Can anyone tell me if and how to make the Fancybox modal close, and the underlying page re-load when the login form is submitted please?

Here's my current code - within a functions.js file:

```
  $(".login-popup").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 310,
    height      : 300,
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
  });
```

And here's my login link:

```
<a class="login-popup" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="/popup/login" title="">Login</a>
```

Thanks for any help,

Ste

Edit 1:

Thanks for the help with this. Sorry for being a complete newbie, but I'm having trouble getting the parent.$.fancybox.close(); to work on the form submit() event. Here's the code I'm now using but it doens't close the window as I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas what? Thanks.

```
$(".login-popup").fancybox({
    closeEffect : 'none',
    'afterClose':function () {
      window.location.reload();
    },
  });

$(".login-form").submit(function(){
  parent.fancyBoxClose();
});
```

Comment: try (inside the page that is opened in fancybox) adding to the `form` tag the attribute `onsubmit="parent.$.fancybox.close();"` check for reference  **[this link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onsubmit)**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think I could use the onsubmit method because the CMS login form tag I was using didn't have an onsubmit parameter. But I've just tried it & the parameter did work even though it wasn't documented! :) The good news is that it closed the modal when the submit button is clicked but the bad news is that it appears this is happening too soon for the login form to work. :( I'm going to have to send the user to a 'success' page after logging in within the modal. When this success page loads, is it possible to make parent.$.fancybox.close(); run on page load within script tags? Thanks

Comment: then, in the success page try adding `<a href="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.close();">close</a>` or `<a href="javascript:;" onclick="parent.$.fancybox.close();">close</a>` whatever it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To close the fancybox from within the iframe, you can use `parent.$.fancybox.close();` on the `form` `submit()` event.

Then add an onClose event on the Fancybox initializer, which would reload the page:

```
$(".login-popup").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 310,
    height      : 300,
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    'afterClose':function () {
        window.location.reload();
    },
  });
```

Comment: `onClosed` is a callback for v1.3.x which is not compatible with v2.x (the version the OP is using) ... use `afterClose` instead

Comment: @JFK Good catch! But my point here was to just illustrate the flow, updated the code!

Comment: Hi there, and thanks for this. I'm having trouble getting the parent.$.fancybox.close(); to work on the form submit() event. I've added some new code above (Edit 1), and any help with getting this final piece of the jigsaw in place would be appreciated, thanks.