# Reload Parent Page if fancybox with php message closed

Tags: php, html

On parent Page I have a link

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe more_info_btn"  href="change-showhide.php?id=<?=$data['id']?>">Change Status</a>
```

Which onclick opens fancybox.

In fancybox a form is created to change status.
After form submission, **`$msg`** is shown.

I want to reload parent page on fancybx close , if form is submitted in fancybox and **`$msg`** is shown.

If No changes are made in fancybox, No need to reload parent page.

Valuable help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410582/close-fancybox-modal-window-and-reload-the-page-after-login-form-has-been-submit check it

Answer (score 0):

As per `fancybox` api documentation `onClosed` Will be called once FancyBox is closed.

The following code shows some callback methods of `fancybox`. this may help you.

```
$("#various7").fancybox({
    onStart     :   function() {
        return window.confirm('Continue?');
    },
    onCancel    :   function() {
        alert('Canceled!');
    },
    onComplete  :   function() {
        alert('Completed!');
    },
    onCleanup   :   function() {
        return window.confirm('Close?');
    },
    onClosed    :   function() {
        alert('Closed!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is the callback 'afterClose' :

```
$(".more_info_btn").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 400,
    height      : 450,
    autoSize    : true,
    closeClick  : false,
    'afterClose':function () {
        window.location.reload();
    },
  });
```